# Delete Key with search only the value JSON/Python 3.3.5

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

i want to search only the Value in my Dictionary. I got this strucutre in my JSONfile

```
{
  "Teilnehmer0": {
    "Anzahl Begleitpersonen": "test", 
    "Betreuer": "test", 
    "Keyword": "test", 
    "Nachname": "test", 
    "Name": "test", 
    "Studiengang": ""
  }, 
  "Teilnehmer1": {
    "Anzahl Begleitpersonen": "test1", 
    "Betreuer": "test1", 
    "Keyword": "test1", 
    "Nachname": "test1", 
    "Name": "test1", 
    "Studiengang": "test1"
  }, 
  "Teilnehmer2": {
    "Anzahl Begleitpersonen": "test2", 
    "Betreuer": "test2", 
    "Keyword": "test2", 
    "Nachname": "test2", 
    "Name": "test2", 
    "Studiengang": "test2"
  }
}
```

So, how i can now search at the same time for the Values "Name", "Nachname" and "Keyword" and when i find the 3 Values in the Key, to remove the hole Key, for example, i search the Values in the key "Teilnehmer2" and i find the 3 values, than i want to remove the hole key Teilnehmer2 from my JSONfile ? I dont know, how to do that :/

Comment: Do you want to actually obtain those 3 values and do something with them or do you want to delete all keys that have "Name", "Nachname" and "Keyword"?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
d = {
  "Teilnehmer0": {
    "Anzahl Begleitpersonen": "test", 
    "Betreuer": "test", 
    "Keyword": "test", 
    "Nachname": "test", 
    "Name": "test", 
    "Studiengang": ""
  }, 
  "Teilnehmer1": {
    "Anzahl Begleitpersonen": "test1", 
    "Betreuer": "test1", 
    "Keyword": "test1", 
    "Nachname": "test1", 
    "Name": "test1", 
    "Studiengang": "test1"
  }, 
  "Teilnehmer2": {
    "Anzahl Begleitpersonen": "test2", 
    "Betreuer": "test2", 
    "Keyword": "test2", 
    "Nachname": "test2", 
    "Name": "test2", 
    "Studiengang": "test2"
  }
}

for key, value in d.items():
  name = value.get('Name')
  nachname = value.get('Nachname')
  keyword = value.get('Keyword')

  # do whatever you want with name, nachname and keyword

  del d[key]
```

In the `for` statement, we're iterate over key/value pairs in the dictionary using [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and for each value, we get the "Name", "Nachname" and "Keyword" before delete the key from the dict using the [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement).

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: this will delete all keys

Comment: I assumed that's what OP is after (since all the 3 items provided had all of "Name", "Nachname" and "Keyword"). I'll make the necessary change when OP replies to my comment.

Comment: I would not presume that the whole json file would be identical on the basis of seeing a very small snippet and if you considered all the dicts to be the same then you would not need `dict.get`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the keys/dicts that contain the keys `"Name", "Nachname","Keyword"`

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if all(x in v for x in ["Name", "Nachname","Keyword"]):
        del d[k]
```